# List index error when using complex indices

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to call a function `testPieceCollision`, but I'm getting a list indexing error:

Here is the definition of `testPieceCollision`:

```
def testPieceCollision(player=None):
    for x in range(5):
        for y in range(5):
            if pieceTilemaps[pieceID][pieceR][y][x]is not None and(gameBoard[pieceY+y][pieceX+x]if player is None else gameBoard[player][pieceY[player]+y][pieceX[player]+x])is not None:
                return True
    return False
```

Here's the error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ninji2701\Desktop\Pile-o-Stuff\Master Stacker\Master Stacker.py", line 525, in <module>
    if testPieceCollision(currentPlayerHandle):
  File "C:\Users\Ninji2701\Desktop\Pile-o-Stuff\Master Stacker\Master Stacker.py", line 28, in testPieceCollision
    if pieceTilemaps[pieceID][pieceR][y][x]is not None and(gameBoard[pieceY+y][pieceX+x]if player is None else gameBoard[player][pieceY[player]+y][pieceX[player]+x])is not None:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

For reference, `player` is an int, `pieceID`, `pieceR`, `pieceX`, and `pieceY` are all int lists, and gameBoard is a complex list structure with a default value of `[[[None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]`×40+`[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]`×5`]`×2`]`

Comment: If `pieceID` and the others are lists, you can't use them to index. Are you intending to index with a list?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  The discrepancy is quite clear: (1) you *know* that you are trying to use a list as an index; (2) as the error message tells you, this is not legal Python.  What confuses you?

Comment: …Whoops. I really should've realized that.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your indexes is a list, that's what the error says. The best way to find out is printing every variable you are using as index, right before the line that throws the error, and put "exit()" on the next line to terminate the code before the line that is throwing the error message.